# Unknown compiler option typeRoots

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have been searching for this for hours now, and can not figure this one out. I am getting 2 compile error in VS2015 when trying to create a new angular 2 application. The errors I get are all the same except for the last word.

> Unknown compiler option 'typeRoots' , 'lib'

I have researched this and seen most of the issue is that it isn't an up to date verison on typescript. I have 2.0.6 installed on my machine and have checked this many times. I have also tried to uncheck $(VSINSTALLDIR) in the tools=>options=> project and solutions.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [ "dom", "es5", "es2015", "es2016" ]
  }
}
```

thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now resolved, what I had to do was restore pc back to before any vs was installed, then reinstall all VS2015 and typescript.

After reinstalling vs2015 i now can use angular2 inside VS

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to version `2.1.4`. I know `typeRoots` works for me. I don't use `lib` option.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your csproj file.

```
<PropertyGroup>        <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked></PropertyGroup>
```